# Start app on user-computer by php application to edit document

Tags: php, web, ms-word

Is it possible to start Word on a user PC by a php application stored on a webserver? All PCs and servers are in a LAN. The situation is as follows: A php app produces a word-document and stores it on fileserver, knowing where to stock it. After this Word (or similar app) should be started on the users PC so that he can work on the document directly on the fileserver. Is there a solution for this situation in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write 2 script, 1 on the server to create the Word docuement and 1 on the clients machine which watches the folder the php file added the file to, then the client machine can initate a script to start word and open the file.

PHP is a server side language so it cannot interact with the clients machine.

The clients machine can run any scripting language you like from PHP, Python, Node and many more depending on what OS you are running on the machine, as long as you initiate a script to watch the folder the server's php placed the file in.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Do you have a script for the client machine or a site where i can find such a script (in VBscript,...)? The server part is already solved.

Comment: Depends on your knowlege of programming?? If you Google it you will find lots of scripts. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files